# PySpark - running processes

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency, pyspark, spark-streaming

In my Spark Streaming (Spark 2.1.0) application, I have the need to build a graph from a file and initializing that graph takes between 5 and 10 seconds.

So I tried initializing it once per executor so it'll be initialized only once.

After running the application, I've noticed that it's initiated much more than once per executor, every time with a different process id (every process has it's own logger).

Doesn't every executor have it's own JVM and it's own process? Or is that only relevant when I develop in JVM languages like Scala/Java?
Do executors in PySpark spawn new processes for new tasks?

And if they do, how can I make sure that my graph object will really only be initiated once?

The way I initialize my object:

```py
class MySingletons(object):
    kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
    tagger = _init_tagger()  # This returns an object with a graph inside of it
```

```py
    @classmethod
    def handle_batch(cls, records_batch):
        analyzed = cls.tagger.tag(records_batch)
        return analyzed
```

And then I call it inside the driver:

```py
def handle_partition(records: Sequence):
    records_lst = list(records)
    if len(records_lst) > 0:
        MySingletons.handle_batch(records_lst)


def handle_rdd(rdd: RDD):
    rdd_values = rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
    rdd_values.foreachPartition(handle_partition)


ssc.union(*streams).filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None).foreachRDD(handle_rdd)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks :)

Comment: please post versions of software components you are using , details of your code snippet and how you are initializing the graph, any screen shots if you have..... without which, cant be answered correctly.

Comment: if you require that level of control, coding directly in Scala would be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

In short, there is significant difference between JVM languages and Python:

- On JVM executors use separate threads.
- In Python executors use separate processes.

Lifetime of Python objects will be limited to a particular child process and each process will have its own "singletons".

Furthermore Python workers can be killed if `spark.python.worker.reuse` if `false` or if there are idle for an extended period of time.

Finally dynamic allocation can complicate things even further.

Depending on the details of the logic, there are quite a few possible workarounds, but there typically quite involved, and not universal.